# Obtener valor de select y utilizarlo en el mismo archivo php

Tags: php, mysql, formularios, post, select

Hola buenos días tengo este código es para llenar un select con php y mysql pero con el valor obtenido debo realizar otra consulta para llenar el otro select dependiendo la selección del primero, necesito hacerlo en el mismo archivo para poder llenar otros inputs que debo agregar desde la consulta de la base de datos, espero me puedan apoyar a obtener en una variable el valor seleccionado del primer select, a continuación mi código:

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" name="reporte">
    <ul >
        <li >
            <label for="proveedor">Proveedor del Servicio: </label> 
                <select id="proveedor" name="proveedor">
                       <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccione Proveedor de Servicio</option>
                <?php

                    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'prueba', '123456', 'intranet_soporte_bitacora');
                    $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
                    $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT * FROM proveedores");
                        while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                            echo '<option value="'.$valores[proveedor].'">'.$valores[proveedor].'</option>';
                                            }
                ?>
        </select></li>
            <li>

            <label for="usuarios">Usuario: </label>
                <select id="usuarios" name="usuarios">
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccione Usuario que Recibirá el Servicio</option>
                     <?php
                        $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'prueba', '123456', 'intranet_soporte_bitacora');
                        $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
                        $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT * FROM empleados ORDER by usuario");
                        while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                            echo '<option value="'.$valores[usuario].'">'.$valores[usuario].'</option>';
                        }
              ?>
            </select></li>
            </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: Puedes usar Javascript/Jquery? El problema que veo es que debes recargar elementos de tu página y para eso se usa AJAX.

Comment: Sí pero con una función o como?

Comment: Para lo que necesitas tienes por fuerza que usar Ajax.  Si no sabes como usarlo tendrias que investigar.

Comment: Hola solo con php no lo puedes hacer al menos sin recargar la pagina. Pasa que si necesitas que se llene automático cuando cargue la pagina debes utilizar ajax / jquery para obtener el valor de un select y con ese enviarlo hacia el servidor y devolver la lista que correspondería al otro select. En este [link](https://www.kumbiaphp.com/blog/2017/11/17/select-anidado-o-select-dependientes/) te dejo un ejemplo de como implementar esto, en realidad es muy sencillo.
Saludos

Comment: Probaste que te devuelve los valores que quieres? en caso de que si prueba con cambiarle las '' por doble "" asi: echo "<option value='".$valores[usuario]."'>"

Comment: perfecto lo revisaré, espero poder lograrlo y comentar la solución, muchas gracias Denis :D

Comment: si devuelve los valores por que he utilizado métodos post para insertar el form y si manda todos los valores, además el select si se llena con la consulta

Comment: me dejas sber como te fue, jeje

Comment: Probaste con cambiar las posiciones de las comillas?

Answer (score 1):

Te explico que pasa. Necesitas abrir una conexión AJAX que es un "túnel" al back-end para traer información sin necesidad de recargar la página por completo.
Te hice un ejemplo utilizando JS/Jquery quizá tenga un par de errores de sintaxis debido a que no tengo el ambiente de desarrollo correcto. Sin embargo la depuración te debería de resultar fácil. Te documenté que hace cada cosa y separé tu código de PHP de USUARIOS, anexo que, tu consulta a tus usuarios quizá esté pero no deberá ser complicado para ti pues sabes como funciona.

TU HTML debería quedar mas o menos así.

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" name="reporte">
    <ul >
        <li >
            <label for="proveedor">Proveedor del Servicio: </label> 
                <select id="proveedor" name="proveedor">
                       <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccione Proveedor de Servicio</option>
                <?php

                    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'prueba', '123456', 'intranet_soporte_bitacora');
                    $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
                    $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT * FROM proveedores");
                        while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                            echo '<option value="'.$valores[proveedor].'">'.$valores[proveedor].'</option>';
                                            }
                ?>
        </select></li>
            <li>

            <label for="usuarios">Usuario: </label>
                <select id="usuarios" name="usuarios">

                </select></li>
            </ul>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  //Función que indica que el documento está listo
  $(function(){ 

    //Detectar el cambio de opción del proveedor
    $(document).on('change','#proveedor',function(){

      //borrar las opciones que están cargadas en los usuarios
      $('#usuarios option').each(function(){
        $(this).remove();
      });

      //Guardar valor seleccionado
      var proveedor = $(this).val();

      //Validar que no esté vacío o nulo
      if( proveedor && proveedor != '' ){

        //Abrir conexión de AJAX
        $.ajax({
          url: 'buscaUsuario.php', //URL donde está el archivo que busca a los usuarios
          method: 'GET', //Verbo de petición del protocolo
          data: {proveedor:proveedor}, //Información que se enviará al PHP
          success:function(respuesta){
            //Respuesta satisfactoria

            //Validar si se creó correctamente el JSON
            if( respuesta.success ){
              var i = 0;

              //Agregar opción por default a usuarios
              $('#usuarios').append('<option disabled selected>Seleccione Usuario que Recibirá el Servicio</option>');

              //Recorrer el nodo de información recopilada
              for (i; i < respuesta.data.length;) {

                //Armar la opción y agregarla al SELECT de usuarios
                let option = '<option value="' + respuesta.data[i].id + '">' + respuesta.data[i].usuario + '</option>';
                $('#usuarios').append(option);
                i++;
              }      

            }

            else{
              alert( respuesta.message );
            }
          },
          error:function(err){
            alert( err );
          }
        })
      }

    });

  });
</script>
```

AHORA TU PHP QUE DEBES NOMBRAR buscaUsuario.php AL MISMO NIVEL QUE TU HTML

```
<?php

  //Agregamos el encabezado para retornar JSON
  header('Content-Type: application/json');

  //Abrimos la conexión a la DB
   $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'prueba', '123456', 'intranet_soporte_bitacora');
   $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

   //Declaramos un arreglo que vamos a retornar
   $arr = array();

   //Validamos que la información que llega no esté vacía,
   //armamos un arreglo asociativo que tendrá la información de retorno
   if( empty($_REQUEST['proveedor']) ){
     $arr = array(
       'success' => false,
       'message' => 'El valor llegó vacío',
       'data' => null
     );
   }

   else{

     //Asignamos el valor que llegó a una variable y hacemos la consulta
     $id = $_REQUEST['proveedor'];
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM empleados ORDER by usuario WHERE proveedor_id = " . $id;

     //Validamos que la consulta esté bien creada
     if( !$r = mysqli_query( $mysqli, $sql )){
       $arr = array(
         'success' => false,
         'message' => 'Consulta mal formada',
         'data' => null
       );
     }

     else{
       //Validamos que la consulta regrese información
       if( mysqli_num_rows( $r ) <= 0 ){
         $arr = array(
           'success' => false,
           'message' => 'La consulta no regresó registros',
           'data' => null
         );
       }

       else{
         //Recorremos la variable para extraer la información y la metemos
         //en un arreglo asociativo que se usara en el Javascript
         $data = array();
         while ($rw = mysqli_fetch_array( $r )) {
           $data[] = array(
             'id' => $rw['id'],
             'usuario' => $rw['usuario']
           );
         }

         //Agregamos la variable al nodo data y ponemos todo exitoso
         $arr = array(
           'success' => true,
           'message' => 'Consulta exitosa',
           'data' => $data
         );
         //Limpiamos la el resultado y liberamos memoria
         mysqli_free_result($r);

        //Cerramos la conexión
        mysqli_close($mysqli);
       }         
     }
   }

   //Retornamos el arreglo con un formato de tipo JSON
   echo json_encode( $arr );
?>
```